# Manually create & sign in user while creating new record - using rails & devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Basically, I'm working on a 'new listing' form, that needs to work whether or not the user is signed in - so if the user isn't signed in, it creates a user and signs them in, then creates the associated listing. I'm using rails 4 with devise, and really just need to know what the best practice is for this scenario, as it seems to be pretty common in web apps.

So, I've got the main user fields (email, pass, pass confirm) inside a fields_for :user tag at the bottom of the listing form, only shown if the user isn't logged in. Its inside the listing form, so the field names are in the form listing[user][email] etc. My create function inside the 'listings' controller currently looks like this:

```
def create

#if not logged in, create user & sign them in
if !user_signed_in?
  @user = User.new(params[:listing].require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation))
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
  else
    @listing.errors.add :base, "Invalid user data"
  end
end

 @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)  
 if @listing.save
   redirect_to listing_url(@listing), notice: 'Success! Now, add some images'
 else
   render "new"
 end  
end
```

This all works fine as long as there aren't any validation errors.  I was thinking I could add render "new" after the @listing.errors.add line, but this doesn't appear to work (still gives an error with the "@listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)" line as the user isn't yet created/signed in. If I enter all the user fields, the user is successfully created & signed in, so it correctly shows the normal listing validation errors.

Anyway, I'm just getting a bit lost as to whether I'm going in the right direction with this - could someone shed some light on how to get this process working 'the rails way'? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. In your question, you said that adding the line `render "new"` doesn't help. Well, that's because it's continuing to execute the rest of the function after that line. What you want to do is exit immediately, so you're not hitting the line `@listing = current_user.listings.build(...)`.

You want `render "new" and return` after `@listing.errors.add :base, ...`, so that it leaves the action as soon as it sees that the user is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That works, but is this the best-practice way to go about it? This way, it doesn't validate any of the listing fields until the user is valid & logged_in. Any way to show the listing validation errors at the same time? Another quick Q - does the User.new method automatically validate the email & passwords through devise?

Comment: @Dave, if this solution worked for you, you should consider accepting it as correct. It's considered both polite and helpful to do so. Also, if you have a follow-up question, you may be well advised to ask it in a separate question for the benefit of other users.